Modelling Rate with Logistic regression
Current practice to model rate i.e. response variable ranging from 0 to 1 is model within the framework of Logistic regression. Both glm function of R and Logit method of statsmodels package in Python allow response variable as continuous variable within [0, 1] to be modelled as Logistic regression.
In this approach the coefficients are estimated using MLE by maximizing the Likelihood function as
$L = \prod {\pi}^{y_i} {\left( 1 - \pi \right)}^{\left( 1 - y_i \right)}$
In Finance, this approach is used to model Recovery rate in a default from corporate loan.
My question is how this approach can be theoretically fit to model any response variable which is continuous with support [0, 1]? That means, if I want to model the Recovery rate using this framework, how can I meaningfully define the distribution of response variable i.e. Recovery rate as Binomial/Bernoulli distribution?

A Binomial/Bernoulli distribution is not continuous as it is only supported on a finite number of integer values.  What you are modelling for $\pi$ is closer to being the $p$ parameter using a Beta distribution (and transforming this probability into log-odds for your logistic regression).

@Henry Thanks for your input. However I still do not comprehend how exactly this falls under beta distribution. If I look into the LF then it appears close to beta distribution however I still cant translate it actual theoretical foundation. Could you please elaborate further?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259131/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-beta-distribution-and-the-logistic-regressi discusses this - you could say that finding the MLE in logistic regression is a frequentist method  with binomial/Bernoulli likelihoods while a beta distribution provides a conjugate Bayesian prior for binomial/Bernoulli likelihoods

Thanks. However I am not going into that direction of Bayesian and frequentist . My question was what is the theoretical basis to model ratio like Recovery rate using Binomial distribution in GLM framework. Why R/Python does not generate error if response variable is not binary but ratio, and provides MLE. How can I be confident that MLE for ratio response variable with Binomial family is indeed correct? More specifically, if response variable is ratio then why the Likelihood function is constructed in that way as if from binomial?

If you have $m$ iid observations $x_1,\cdots,x_m$ from a binomial distribution with known parameter $n$ and unknown parameter $\pi$ then the associated likelihood is (proportional to) $\prod\limits_1^m {n \choose x_i}\pi^{x_i}(1-\pi)^{n-x_i}$.
Turning the observations into proportions  $y_i=\frac{x_1}{n}$, this becomes $$\prod_1^m {n \choose ny_i}\pi^{ny_i}(1-\pi)^{n(1-y_i)} = \left(\prod_1^m {n \choose ny_i}\right)\left(\prod_1^m \pi^{y_i}(1-\pi)^{1-y_i}\right)^n$$ and as a likelihood for $\pi$ this is maximised when $\prod\limits_1^m \pi^{y_i}(1-\pi)^{1-y_i}$ is maximised.
When $n=1$, i.e. Bernoulli distributions rather than binomial distributions and each observation of $x_i$ and $y_i$ is $0$ or $1$, all these expressions are $\prod\limits_1^m \pi^{x_i}(1-\pi)^{1-x_i}=\prod\limits_1^m \pi^{y_i}(1-\pi)^{1-y_i}$ and the argument is direct.
